# Unable to form a link of a file which is in sites-available to a directory sites-enabled in remote server using ansible?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, automation, ansible, yaml

Unable to form a link of a file which is in sites-available to a directory sites-enabled in remote server using ansible?

This is command I want to execute using file module of ansible:
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/wsgi-keystone.conf /etc/apache2/
sites-enabled

This is the code of the task i am using:

```
- name: Enable the Identity service virtual hosts
  file: src=/etc/apache2/sites-available/wsgi-keystone.conf dest=/etc/apache2/sites-enabled state=link owner=root group=root mode=0644
```

By the way I am running the playbook as root user:

Getting the following error:

```
fatal: [10.0.1.32]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "gid": 0, "group": "root", "mode": "0755", "msg": "refusing to convert between directory and link for /etc/apache2/sites-enabled", "owner": "root", "path": "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled", "size": 4096, "state": "directory", "uid": 0}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to set a link on `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` which is obviously a directory.

You have to define a full qualified filename:

```
- name: Enable the Identity service virtual hosts
  file: src=/etc/apache2/sites-available/wsgi-keystone.conf dest=/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wsgi-keystone.conf state=link owner=root group=root mode=0644
```